# Read XML in spark 2.2 with java and expected output in key value format

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a sample xml file and need to parse it and convert it into key value in spark dataset[Version 2.2] in java [1.8]

sample.xml -

```
               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

             -<RECORD>
               -<PROP NAME="xxx">
                    <PVAL>123</PVAL>
                </PROP> 
                -<PROP NAME="yyy">
                    <PVAL>456</PVAL>
                </PROP> 
               -<PROP NAME="zzz">
                    <PVAL>786</PVAL>
                </PROP> 
             -<RECORD>
```

Tried with below code -

```
            Dataset<Row> xmlDS =  spark.read()
                                .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
                                .option("rowTag", "RECORD")
                               .load("sample.xml");

           XMLDS.printSchema();


           root
           |-- PROP: array (nullable = true)
           |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
           |    |    |-- PVAL: string (nullable = true)
           |    |    |-- _NAME: string (nullable = true)
```

output I got from above one -

```
                +---------------------------------
                |PROP                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                |
                +---------------------------------
                |[[123,xxx], [456,yyy], [786,zzz]]
```

I  want Expected output in key value pair format in Dataset

```
         NAME                   PVAL
         -----------------------------
         xxx                     123
         yyy                     456
         zzz                     786
```

Can some one help on this ?.Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All **you need is change the `rowTag`** and add a `rootTag` as

```
Dataset<Row> xmlDS =  spark.read()
        .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
        .option("rootTag", "RECORD")
        .option("rowTag", "PROP")
        .load("sample.xml");

xmlDS.printSchema();
xmlDS.show(false);
```

which should give you

```
root
 |-- PVAL: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _NAME: string (nullable = true)

+----+-----+
|PVAL|_NAME|
+----+-----+
|123 |xxx  |
|456 |yyy  |
|786 |zzz  |
+----+-----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful